# Is SecCertificateCopyPublicKey function available in iOS SDK 8.2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, security

I am trying to use this function to retrieve public key from a certificate.

```
@import Security
SecCertificateCopyPublicKey (SecCertificateRef certificate, SecKeyRef *key)
```

Note- The above code is just a snippet. 
I am using Xcode Version 6.2 (6C131e) and iOS SDK 8.2. SecCertificateCopyPublicKey function seems to be not available in iOS SDK 8.2. Only the below functions are available in iOS 8.2 SDK on SecCertificate.... Could someone clarify on the availability of SecCertificateCopyPublicKey function in the iOS SDK?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't find it either in the sdks headers but it is in the docs .. and there is no indication it was removed

You can try defining it yourself at the beginning of your m file so the compiler can see it
(the header just tells it it is there - it doesn't really 'do' anything)

that way you can use it

**at the same time I'd file a bug for that**

---

## works on IOS 8.2

```
//forward define it
//IF it doesnt exist, you get an error but if it exists you can use it!
OSStatus SecCertificateCopyPublicKey ( SecCertificateRef certificate, SecKeyRef *key );

//my class
@implementation M42Defaults 

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        //use it
        OSStatus s = SecCertificateCopyPublicKey(nil, nil);
        //...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: @VevekPandian What do you mean? :)

Comment: You can try defining it yourself in the bridge header so swift picks it up (the header just tells it it is there - it doesn't really 'do' anything)                         --Could you please explain this how do we include header and use SecCertificateCopyPublicKey in iOS? I am using Objective-C for development

Comment: I am able to build the project. Thanks. Found another problem in printing SecKeyRef. Could you please give some pointers?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285904/printing-seckeyref-reference-using-nslog-in-objective-c

Comment: What is meant by forward define? How did I build the project even though Apple hasn't defined SecCertificateCopyPublicKey in the iOS 8.2 SDK? Also, I found there are lot many functions like SecCertificateCopyCommonName, SecCertificateCopyEmailAddresses
SecCertificateCopyLongDescription and so on are not available in iOS 8.2 SDK

Comment: use SecTrustCopyPublicKey